# "du darfst dir die deswegen "

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a movie I heard the mother telling her daughter who is a teacher:

> Martha, die Sache mit dieser Lili war schlimm, aber du darfst dir die deswegen nicht die Freude am Beruf verderben lassen.

Can anyone tell me what does "*die deswegen*" here mean ?

Comment: Are you sure the  mother said exactly this?

Comment: yes there's a subtitle in german

Comment: Seems to be an error. Throw "die" away, is better then.

Comment: Please check here: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/deswegen

Comment: The correct verb is "verderben" (verdebren is wrong).

Comment: Besides obvious errors like this one, please note that subtitles are not always an exact transcript of the spoken words. They might be shortened or simplified for better readability.

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors in

> Aber du darfst dir die deswegen nicht die Freude am Beruf verdebren lassen.

1. The word »die« doesn't fit into this sentence. It has neither a semantic nor a grammatical function. It should be omitted.
2. The word »verdebren« is not part of the German vocabulary. But »verderben« would perfectly fit on it's place.

This is a correct sentence:

> Aber du darfst dir deswegen nicht die Freude am Beruf verderben lassen.